# Mi página no guarda los datos en la base de datos, a pesar de establecer conexión esta

Tags: php

Se supone que debería recuperar las variables usuario (realname) y password (pass), pero a pesar de establecer conexión con la base de datos no guarda las variables en los datos correspondientes.

mi código php es

```
<?php

        $db =  MySQLi_connect("localhost", "u554150303_logos","mendoza98", "u554150303_logos");

if(isset($_POST['realname']))   {

    $realname=$_POST['realname'];

}
if(isset($_POST['pass']))   {

    $pass= $_POST['pass'];

}


    require("connect_db.php");
//la variable  $mysqli viene de connect_db que lo traigo con el require("connect_db.php");      



                //require("connect_db.php");
//la variable  $mysqli viene de connect_db que lo traigo con el require("connect_db.php");
                $query=mysqli_query($db, "INSERT INTO login 
 VALUES($realname','$pass','2')");
                //echo 'Se ha registrado con exito';
                echo ' <script language="javascript">alert("Usuario registrado con éxito");</script> ';







?>
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Bienvenido a SOes. Intenta añadir una comilla simple `'` en esta parte `$realname'` por `'$realname'` ten en cuenta también si tienes más campos en tu tabla **login**, la sentencia no sería correcta, deberías añadir sus campos, algo así `INSERT INTO login (campo1,campo2,campo3)  VALUES ('$realname','$pass','2')`. También veo dos conexiones a tu Base de Datos, uno al principio de tu código y otro mediante `require`, podrías eliminar uno de los dos.

Answer (score 0):

creo que a tu query le hace falta asignarle los campos a los que quieres que guarde los datos que tienes en las variables

```
$query=mysqli_query($db, "INSERT INTO login (campo1, campo2) VALUES ($realname','$pass','2')");
```

El '2' no se para que lo ocupas, le require no es necesario (), e intenta ponerlo al principio del código.

```
<?php
require "connect_db.php";
```

Comment: Los nombres de las columnas no son obligatorios, aún con eso debería funcionar

Comment: Igual veo dos conexiones a tu base, deja el require y elimina/comenta el $db =  MySQLi_connect